# CSS position absolute elements not aligning properly with their sibling elements

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, flexbox, css-position

I'm building out a custom `Tooltip` component in React that allows for rendering both to the right of the element as well as below it. I've decided to handle the functionality by having the `Tooltip` accept children which it then renders, and when those children are hovered the tip itself, positioned absolutely, will become visible through CSS classes. The effect works exactly how I want when the elements are stacked in a column and the tooltip is set to render to the right, but when the elements are laid out in a row with the tip rendering on the bottom, the tip itself becomes misaligned from the child its rendering -- the length of the tooltip text seems to offset it to the right.

Here's a codesandbox displaying the problem. You'll see that in the first state, when the elements are in a column, the tip is aligned perfectly. Click the button to toggle them into a row format and hover again to see that they are now misaligned:

https://codesandbox.io/s/busted-tooltip-obf0h1?file=/src/Tooltip.scss

How can I get the tips to align centered with their child element when I've chosen to have them render below it?

```
// Tooltip.jsx

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Tooltip.scss';

const Tooltip = ({ children, label, orientation = 'right' }) => {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className={`Tooltip__Container ${orientation}`}>
      <div
        onMouseOver={() => setIsHovered(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
      <div className={`Tooltip__Inner ${orientation} ${isHovered ? 'Visible' : ''}`}>
        {orientation === 'right' && <div className={`Tooltip__PointLeft ${isHovered ? 'Visible' : ''}`} />}
        {orientation === 'bottom' && <div className={`Tooltip__PointUp ${isHovered ? 'Visible' : ''}`} />}
        <div className={`Tooltip ${orientation} ${isHovered ? 'Visible' : ''}`}>
          {label}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tooltip;
```

```
/* Tooltip.scss */

@import 'src/styles/colors.scss', 'src/styles/typography.scss', 'src/styles/breakpoints.scss';

.Tooltip__Container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;

  &.right {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  &.bottom {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.Tooltip__Inner {
  display: flex;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  &.right {
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  &.bottom {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

.Tooltip__Inner.right.Visible {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 3.5rem;
}

.Tooltip__Inner.bottom.Visible {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 3.5rem;
}

.Tooltip__PointLeft.Visible {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 10px solid $white-transparent;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.Tooltip__PointUp.Visible {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid $white-transparent;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.Tooltip {
  background-color: $white-transparent;
  padding: .75rem;
  border-radius: 3px;

  @include MainFont;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For quick solution, you can update the bottom class inside .Tooltip__Inner

with this:

```
  &.bottom {
    flex-direction: column;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  
  }
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!